# Unload a ruby class

Tags: ruby

I have the following in the file a.rb:

```
require foo
```

and i need to unload foo, to load the foo from b.rb, c.rb and other files.

How i can do?

Comment: what is foo, and why do you have classes with the same name doing different things in different files?

Comment: in a.rb:
class Foo ... end

I need it because i have to run Foo.bar in each rb file, and i cant edit rb files.

Comment: is each Foo.bar different? or are they the same Foo?

Comment: each Foo.bar is a function that does different things, and i need to run them all

Comment: so you have 1 file, the requires a.rb, b.rb,c.rb. and each of the a.rb, b,rb, c.rb require's 'foo' but a different foo, to do a different thing?   Err my head hurts just thinking about it.  well if you just keep opening up the Foo class, and replacing bar, does that work, or does each file have to require foo from an external source?

Comment: No,no no. I have 1 file, that need to run Foo.bar placed inside many rb files. simply.

Comment: why can't you make something like `class B; def bar;...end; end`, `class C;def bar;...end; end` - so only the method `bar` remains the same and could easily be called without all that unloading magic?

Comment: I said "i can't edit rb files"

Comment: you don't have to edit the files, in ruby you can re-open the class, and change/add to it from any file. Once the class is loaded in you can change it dynamically on the fly, that is what @lwe and I are talking about.  But I am still at a loss to what exactly you are trying to do with With 1 file calling Foo.bar in other files...

Comment: as i said below, the method is not overrided, and its called always in the first object that i requie

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)
```

assuming your class is named `Foo`.

Comment: irb(main):002:0> require 'timeout'

=> true

irb(main):004:0> Object.send(:remove_const, :Timeout)

=> Timeout

irb(main):005:0> require 'timeout'

=> false

Comment: mhh, yes, because require checks if it has already loaded that lib, maybe you need to use `load` instead of `require`... why do you need to unload that const anyway? can't you use modules or anything to shield them?
PS: you need to append the file extension in `load`

Comment: but aren't there multiple files, so this shouldn't be a problem at all? so shouldn't some hacky magic like `%w{a b c d}.each { |f| require(f); Foo.bar; Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo) }` work "as expected" in your case - though I don't really recommend it. Just seems strange, having all these .rb files defining the same class + method.

Comment: ^^ it works, `a.rb`, `b.rb`, `c.rb` and `d.rb` look like: `class Foo; def self.bar; puts __FILE__ end end` and then I have the main loop as described above in a file named `prg.rb`... and the output is, as expected :) => `./a.rb ./b.rb ./c.rb ./d.rb`

Comment: Sorry but for me after the first cycle defined?(Foo) returns false

Comment: %w{a b c d}.each { |f| require(f); Foo.bar if defined?(Foo); Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo) }

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the unloading part, but using `load` instead of `require` will always reload the file.  However, when you use load you will need to include the .rb so in your case it would be `load 'foo.rb'` .

See http://www.fromjavatoruby.com/2008/10/require-vs-load.html

[Kernel#load docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load)
[Kernel#require docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

Comment: The problem with this, is if you define an instance variable inside of a class, and load the file, and then remove the instance variable, and then load the file again, the instance variable still exists even though you removed it. Reason is because when you define a class twice, the second definition adds onto what already exists, rather than completely redefining it.

Comment: In a production environment that shouldn't be stopped, this would allow access to methods that were intended to be deleted from the class and "reloaded" using load