# Multiple classes of the same name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I have an existing codebase of unit tests where the same classes are defined for each test, and a program that iterates over them. Something like this:

```
test_files.each do |tf|   
  load "tests/#{tf}/"+tf
  test=     ::Kernel.const_get("my_class")
  Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run( test )
```

While working on these tests, I've realized that ruby allows you to `require` classes with the same name from different files, and it merges the methods of the two. This leads to problems as soon as the class hierarchy is not the same: `superclass mismatch for class ...`

Unfortunately, simply [unloading the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424663/unload-a-ruby-class) is not enough, as there are many other classes in the hierarchy that remain loaded.

Is there a way to execute each test in a different global namespace?

While I figure that using modules would be the way to go, I'm not thrilled with idea of changing the hundreds of existing files by hand.

--EDIT--

Following Cary Swoveland's suggestion, I've moved the test running code to a separate `.rb` file and am running it using backticks. While this seems to work well, loading the ruby interpreter and `require`ing all the libraries again has a considerable overhead. Also, cross-platform compatibility requires some extra work.

Comment: How about using backticks or `system` to run each test separately?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That seems to mostly work (see edit), thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Why do you need to define classes in your tests? Maybe you have a reason for it, but it seems like a bit of a test smell.

Comment: @MarkThomas These are not actual unit tests in the traditional sense, but functional tests using the [Sipper](http://www.agnity.com/sipper/) framework, which is OO and requires your tests to be classes. I'm not able to judge if the framework *needs* to be written in such a way, but the fact is that it is.

Comment: What about to wrap classes with modules dinamically in your loop?

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko If I did that, I imagine that things would break, because there's references to the classes from several other classes (it's a complex hierarchy)

Answer (score 2):

first I wanted to propose the following solution:

```
#main.rb
modules = []

Dir.foreach('include') do |file|
  if file =~ /\w/
    new_module = Module.new

    load "include/#{file}"

    new_module.const_set("StandardClass", StandardClass)

    Object.send(:remove_const, :StandardClass)

    modules << new_module
  end

end

modules.each do |my_module|
  my_module::StandardClass.standard_method
end

#include/first.rb
class StandardClass
  def self.standard_method
    puts "first method"
  end
end

#include/second.rb
class StandardClass
  def self.standard_method
    puts "second method"
  end
end
```

this wraps each class with it's own module and calls the class inside it's module:

```
$ruby main.rb
second method
first method
```

But as you answered there are references to other classes so modules can break them.
I checked this by calling the third class from one of the wrapped classes and got:

```
include/second.rb:5:in `standard_method': uninitialized constant StandardClass::Independent (NameError)
```

so probably using backticks is better solution but I hope my answer will be helpful for some other similar situations.