# Running external Ruby program from Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run some tests in Ruby that requires running external Ruby files/programs.

In Windows console I use irb to run Ruby program that calls another Ruby program located in this same directory like this:

```
irb(main):018:0> puts system "ruby1.8 tmp.rb"
false
=> nil
```

However it always return false.

How can I solve this problem.

I have several versions of Ruby installed on Windows and I need to run a specific version of Ruby chosen on the command line.

I have already tried to rename executable ruby.exe to ruby1.8.exe and it works properly from the command line but not with the 'system' command.

[Multiple classes of the same name in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710017/multiple-classes-of-the-same-name-in-ruby)

Comment: have you tried puts system "ruby tmp.rb" ?

Comment: show the content of `tmp.rb` file

Comment: For me, that is the wrong approach. Normally you would do the following: require or load the external Ruby program; call the method that is called by calling it external (no argument). This will work all the time.

Comment: What happens if you run `ruby1.8 tmp.rb` directly from the Windows console?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> system returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for
>   non zero exit status.

Use backticks instead of `system` to capture the output:

```
output = `ruby tmp.rb`
p output
```