# Ruby on Rails - unload libraries in the /lib path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, libraries, require

**The situation**

The general idea is this: in the `create` method (in the controller) depending on a parameter, I have to run one of three methods as following:

```
case a
when 1..5
  runMethod1(a)
when 6
  runMethod2
when String
  runMethod3(a)
else
  puts "I have no idea what to do with that."
end
```

These methods are also defined in the same controller. Now, each method calls a particular library by using `require`. Those libraries aren't gems, they are files coded by me and located in the  framework `/lib` path.

```
def runMethod1(a)
    require 'my_first_library'
    ...
end
```

What I am trying to do here is calling the library only when I need it, because each method might have an important processing and/or memory load on the system and I don't want to call all the libraries at the beginnig because I don't know if they all are gonna be used.

**The Question**

I'd like to know if Rails takes care of unloading this libraries when the method has finished or if it keeps it after the first call.

Comment: P/S: I found [this][1] and [this][2] questions but they talk about Ruby and though it might be useful to this case, I don't know if Rails already handles it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753060/is-it-possible-to-unload-un-require-a-ruby-library
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424663/unload-a-ruby-class

Comment: Have you heard that Rails preloads every library in the app in production environment? Why do you care of loading/unloading certain classes/modules?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I didn't know that, I'm currently working in development mode. I just asked because I don't like the idea of having unrequired libraries consuming memory. You know if there's a way of avoiding this preload?