# Isolating meta-programming specs that fail intermittantly (open classes / monkey patching)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to refactor a spec that currently passes or fails based off the order in which the examples are run.

Spec is below.

If the first example runs first, the spec passes.

If the second test runs before the first, it fails. I understand why it fails -- there are three subclasses of `FieldExtractor` in ObjectSpace so the assertion `expect(FieldExtractor.all.size).to eq 2` will be false.

```
RSpec.describe FieldExtractor do

  it 'keeps track of subclasses' do
    class TotalExtractor < FieldExtractor
    end
    class VendorExtractor < FieldExtractor
    end

    expect(FieldExtractor.all).to include(TotalExtractor)
    expect(FieldExtractor.all).to include(VendorExtractor)
    expect(FieldExtractor.all.size).to eq 2
  end

  it 'keeps track of extracted field' do
    class ConfiguredExtractor < FieldExtractor
      extracts :vendor
    end

    expect(ConfiguredExtractor.field).to eq :vendor
  end
end
```

My question is how to fix this intermittant test failure.

Is there an elegant way around this? Is the way I'm testing this totally off-base?

One solution I got working but don't particularly care for is defining all the subclasses at the beginning of the spec (outside the examples) so that I know exactly how many there should be. I don't like this solution because I have many examples with many subclasses and it doesn't seem to scale well.

Comment: `before(:each) { FieldExtractor.clear }` where the implementation of `clear` is up to you (might be [assigning constant to `nil`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3424706/2035262).) My experience says that you’ll nevertheless have it (`#clear`) sooner or later required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [stub_const](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/mutating-constants/stub-undefined-constant) to stub an undefined const, that will be automatically removed after test execution:

```
it 'keeps track of subclasses' do
  stub_const('TotalExtractor', Class.new(FieldExtractor))
  stub_const('VendorExtractor', Class.new(FieldExtractor))

  expect(FieldExtractor.all).to include(TotalExtractor)
  expect(FieldExtractor.all).to include(VendorExtractor)
  expect(FieldExtractor.all.size).to eq 2
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.